# Add a col using file name

Tags: awk, zsh

I have ~ 100 files, they are a.vcf; b.vcf, d.vcf......
For example:
a.vcf

```
##contig= ID=chr1,length=249250621 
##contig= ID=chr2,length=243199373 
##contig= ID=chr3,length=198022430 
##contig= ID=chr4,length=191154276
```

b.vcf

```
##contig= ID=chr5,length=180915260 
##contig= ID=chr6,length=171115067 
##contig= ID=chr7,length=159138663 
##contig= ID=chr8,length=146364022 
##contig= ID=chr9,length=141213431 
##contig= ID=chr10,length=135534747
```

I want to add additional col as the last col, for examples, new file a_a.vcf
a_a.vcf

```
##contig= ID=chr1,length=249250621  a.vcf
##contig= ID=chr2,length=243199373  a.vcf
##contig= ID=chr3,length=198022430  a.vcf
##contig= ID=chr4,length=191154276  a.vcf
```

For single vcf file, I used the following code:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0 " name_file"; next;}{print $0 " " FILENAME;}' a.vcf
```

Then I want to apply this to all the files in this folder.

```
for d in *.vcf; do
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0 " name_file"; next;}{print $0 " " FILENAME;}' a_$d
done
```

But I found the -zsh replaced $0, How could I fix the problem?

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print -zsh  name_file; next;}{print -zsh   FILENAME;}' a_a.vcf 
awk 'NR == 1 {print -zsh  name_file; next;}{print -zsh   FILENAME;}' a_b.vcf 
awk 'NR == 1 {print -zsh  name_file; next;}{print -zsh   FILENAME;}' a_c.vcf
```

Comment: If you're using `zsh`, why is this tagged `bash`?

Comment: Variables are only supposed to be replaced inside double quotes, not single quotes. How are you running this script?

Comment: Is it in a here-doc?

Comment: @puppetshow: In the code you posted, the argument to `awk`, including the `$0`, is in single quotes. Therefore zsh does **not** touch it and passes the string literally to awk.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `AWK` is not limited to single input file, you might provide multiple files to single `awk` by using filenames sheared by spaces, in your case try

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print $0 " name_file"; next;}{print $0 " " FILENAME;}' a.vcf b.vcf c.vcf
```

which should give same output as

```
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0 " name_file"; next;}{print $0 " " FILENAME;}' a.vcf
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0 " name_file"; next;}{print $0 " " FILENAME;}' b.vcf
awk 'NR == 1 {print $0 " name_file"; next;}{print $0 " " FILENAME;}' c.vcf
```

Note that I used `FNR` in place of `NR` i.e. number of line inside file rather than (global) number of line. As suggested in comments, you might further ameliorate your code exploiting `OFS` variable as follows

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=" "}FNR == 1 {print $0, "name_file"; next}{print $0, FILENAME}' a.vcf b.vcf c.vcf
```

If you want to know more about OFS and other read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Regarding `print $0 " name_file"` and `print $0 " " FILENAME` - let `OFS` do it's job - `print $0, "name_file"` and `print $0, FILENAME`. That way if you want to change the output separator to a tab or a comma you only have to do it 1 place, `OFS="whatever"`. You don't need the `;`s before the `}`s btw. Also - there's nothing GNU-specific about your answer, all awks can process multiple input files at once.